# how to loop images using foreach loop

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to loop images from Facebook `invitable_friends` API using  `foreach` loop

```
$beranda = json_decode(get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/$user->id/invitable_friends?fields=id,picture,name&limit=7&access_token=$accessToken"))->data;

foreach($beranda as $friendsid){


echo  '<img src="'.$friendsid->picture.'">';
 }
```

facing this error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in
```

Thia is the structure of `$beranda`

```
Array
  (
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => AVkUphJYSPksSJ47kLM8PGm8cOAjlNLG5NWUMp5IhdSCWkziShWsSVkRdVx1Z73jeu7B73bRzYnecUqD27V3xO36Uh27LD16mVZlRKGKgDLZIQ
        [picture] => stdClass Object
            (
                [data] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [is_silhouette] => 
                        [url] => https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13731636_1671465926510554_2031112688215377192_n.jpg?oh=5a85a07de9ab4011e17378a38bac941c&oe=5831B7E6
                    )

            )

        [name] => Sam Saifi
    )
```

var dump of `$friendsid->picture`

```
       object(stdClass)#38 (1) {
           ["data"]=>
             object(stdClass)#39 (2) {
              ["is_silhouette"]=>
                 bool(false)
                    ["url"]=>
              string(145) "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/10155363_1386729058279575_5046516924942639505_n.jpg?oh=f55ea91f39815a7fb9661e65899d0a02&oe=581B8AE2"
```

}
}

Comment: If its any help, the error means that you are trying to echo out an object, which you can not do, you need to call a method on that object 'picture'. Something like $friendsid->picture->???

Comment: Thanks but i got blank image with no url

Comment: i use $friendsid->picture->url

Comment: run `echo '<pre>'; print_r($beranda); echo '</pre>';` and check the structure of the given object...

Comment: and also after that try `echo '<pre>', var_dump($friendsid->picture);` and edit you post to show the results, thanks.

Comment: try something like `echo  '<img src="' . $friendsid->picture->data->url . '">'; `

Comment: Okay Post Updated now

Comment: Thank you so much for this its working Now

Comment: Cool, if you could accept my answer that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your print_r result you need to change your line...

```
echo  '<img src="'.$friendsid->picture.'">';
```

to

```
echo '<img src="' . $friendsid->picture->data->url . '">';
```

because you are calling a parameter [url], within an object [data], within another object [picture], within another parent object. I would recomment a bootcamp course on object oriented php, anyway Glad it works!